# gitignore file from multiple subdirectory

Tags: git, gitignore

I know tittle is little confusing, I have below structure where I want to delete specific sub-directory and file extensions. I try to use wildcard `**` but I dont think its working

```
Main/AllOn/bin/Debug     
Main/AllOff/bin/Debug    
Main/Auto/bin/Debug/    
Main/Manual/bin/Debug
```

What is the best way to ignore files in `bin/Debug` folder?

I have try this but didn't worked for me
`Main/**/bin/Debug/*.exe` to ignore all the .exe files
`Main/**/bin/Debug/bin` ignore the bin sub-directory under Debug

Comment: Your examples should work to ignore the `Debug/bin` directory and `.exe` files. Are those files already tracked by git? If so, you'll need to remove them with `git rm --cached <file>` before `.gitignore` rules will take effect.

Comment: @JustinHoward I think thats whats going on. Is remove means deleting the file from source code?

Comment: `git rm --cached` removes them from git, but leaves them on your local filesystem. So yes, the file will be deleted from your git repository (it will still be available in the git history).

Comment: @JustinHoward Thanks a lot!